# Can an external Mesh be assigned to a Bone that is part of an armature of another Mesh?

Tags: rigging

As per title.
In the particular case, I have a snail, where the body has an armature assigned to it, while the shell is another mesh.
I would like to assign the shell, that obviously doesn't ben in any way, to a single bone that I dedicated for it in the body armature.
Is it possible/convenient/nonsense, ecc.?
Do you think it's better if I merge the meshes together?
What if one prefers to keep the objects separate for needs of workflow?

Comment: I would keep the meshes separate, and it isn't even necessary in most cases to have a dedicated bone. Hats and sunglasses parent to the head bone, weapons or tools to hand.r, etc. It's a pretty common use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Select the object, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the bone you want, parent with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*. You could also joint the shell to the body and assign its vertices to the right vertex group, it may give the exact same result.